# Using \if in a tabularx

Tags: conditionals, tabularx

I am trying to use `\if` within a `tabularx` environment. This works:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{x} 
    \setcounter{x}{0}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|l}
        \stepcounter{x}
            \ifnum\value{x}=20
            it is 20
            \else
            it is not
            \fi
            \\
    \end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

But of course has no columns. When I try to add them like this:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{x} 
    \setcounter{x}{0}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|l}
        \stepcounter{x}
            \ifnum\value{x}=20
            it is & 20
            \else
            it is & not
            \fi
            \\
    \end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 18. \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Why can't you use this `it is & \ifnum\value{x}=20\relax
            20\else not\fi\\ `?

Comment: @JagathAR well, my actual table has much more columns and the code gets ugly when I have to put the if into every cell.

Comment: You could have a macro `\TestX{20}{20}{not}`. Where `\def\TestX#1#2#3{\ifnum\value{x}=#1\relax #2\else #3\fi}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional cannot straddle two cells. However you can use `\ifthenelse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{x}
%\setcounter{x}{0}

\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\stepcounter{x}%
\ifthenelse{\value{x}=20}{it is & 20}{it is & not}\\
\setcounter{x}{20}%
\ifthenelse{\value{x}=20}{it is & 20}{it is & not}\\
\end{tabular}

\setcounter{x}{0}

\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{c|X}
\stepcounter{x}%
\ifthenelse{\value{x}=20}{it is & 20}{it is & not}\\
\setcounter{x}{20}%
\ifthenelse{\value{x}=20}{it is & 20}{it is & not}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it can if you're careful (and brave)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle White lies sometimes are better than the crude truth. `;-)`

Comment: you just like using my packages

Answer (score 3):

If you must walk on a tightrope then:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{x} 
    \setcounter{x}{0}
   \newcommand\zz[1]{#1}

\centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X}
        \stepcounter{x}
            \ifnum\value{x}=20
            \zz{it is & 20}
            \else
            \zz{it is & not}
            \fi
            \\
    \end{tabularx} 

    \setcounter{x}{19}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X}
        \stepcounter{x}
            \ifnum\value{x}=20
            \zz{it is & 20}
            \else
            \zz{it is & not}
            \fi
            \\
    \end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```