# Using a command to generate a table row in tabularray

Tags: alignment, catcodes, tabularray

I have a command that generates a table row for insertion into a `tblr` environment as shown below:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\MyRow[2]{
    #1 & #2 \\
}

\begin{tblr}{l l}
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
    %\MyRow{E}{F}   % Fails here with "Misplaced alignment tab character &"
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

The command used to work with `tabu` but with `tblr` it produces an error that the alignment character `&` is misplaced:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

I tried overriding the category code of `&` with `\catcode38=12` but it didn't help. How do I generate a tblr row from a custom command?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to section ["3.2.3 Expand Macros First" of the manual of the package tabularray](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf#subsection.3.2.3) you need to use the key `expand=\MyRow`. You only get top-level-expansion of `\MyRow`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\MyRow[2]{#1 & #2 \\}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\MyRow]{l l}
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
    \MyRow{E}{F}% Does not fail with "Misplaced alignment tab character &".
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The question ["tabularray: How to comment out some rows using \if condition inside a table stored in a macro?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622683/tabularray-how-to-comment-out-some-rows-using-if-condition-inside-a-table-stor/622907) and its answers provide some trickery for getting more control over expansion.