Abut two tabularray tables vertically
I need to make two Tabularrays abut.  I cannot merge them into a single table.  How do I get rid of all of the space above and below a Tabularray?
My answer may be related to SetTblrOuter as described in an answer to this question but I'm struggling to make it work: Increase the space between the table relative to the text above and below.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
      row{1} = {red!20},
      hline{1} = {solid},
      hline{2} = {solid},
    }
  HW & Chapter & Problems \\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1}={black!20},
    hline{2} = {solid}
  }
  \SetCell[r=1]{c} 1 & 1.6 & Do \# 1-10\\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1-2}={black!20},
    hline{3} = {solid}
  }
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2 & 2.1 & Do \# 1-10 \\
                     & 2.2 & Do \# 1-10 \\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\end{document}

This code generates the following, where the white stripe between the 3 tables appears to  vary in size depending on context meaning that putting in a fixed negative vspace does not seem to work in general.


Can you give an example that shows why you can't merge them into a single table?  The answer in this case is clearly that you should do that.

Sure.  I am a teacher.  The assignments for my class are used in slides, exam reviews, final exam reviews, etc.  I want to have a single point of definition so that the information is kept in sync (I don't want to have to change the definition of HW#1 in 5 different places).  So I have the homework assignments defined in one file, with each assignment done individually.  Then, if I am doing the slides for a day, it has the ONE needed assignment.  If I am doing the exam review, it includes the 8 relevant assignments.  When I do the final it has all 20 assingments.

The real situation is a bit more complicated than this, but I hope it illustrates what I am doing.

Each assignment is wrapped in a comparison statement so that I can select which assignment(s) I want for any particular purpose.  Tabularray won't allow me to easily put IF statements within a table (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622683/tabularray-how-to-comment-out-some-rows-using-if-condition-inside-a-table-stor) , so I'm stuck wrapping a complete table definition for each assignment.

Adding \nointerlineskip before the second and the third tables will do the trick:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
      row{1} = {red!20},
      hline{1} = {solid},
      hline{2} = {solid},
    }
  HW & Chapter & Problems \\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\nointerlineskip
\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1}={black!20},
    hline{2} = {solid}
  }
  \SetCell[r=1]{c} 1 & 1.6 & Do \# 1-10\\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\nointerlineskip
\begin{tblr}{width={\linewidth},colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1-2}={black!20},
    hline{3} = {solid}
  }
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2 & 2.1 & Do \# 1-10 \\
                     & 2.2 & Do \# 1-10 \\
\end{tblr}%                                                                     

\end{document}



From your comments I think you really should use a single tabular, but with a dynamic content.
For example, define a command to add some homework
\tl_clear_new:N \g_donham_hw_tl

\cs_new:Nn \donham_add_hw:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \g_donham_hw_tl { #1 \\ }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \addhomework }{ m }
  {
    \donham_add_hw:n { #1 }
  }

and another to retrieve all previously given homework
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \gethomework { }
  {
    \tl_use:N \g_donham_hw_tl
  }

You can now add homework with
\addhomework{1 & 1.6 & Do \# 1-10}

\addhomework{%
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2 & 2.1 & Do \# 1-10 \\
  & 2.2 & Do \# 1-10
}

Finally, you have to set tabularray to use \gethomework
\begin{tblr}[
    expand=\expanded,
    ]{
    width={\linewidth},
    colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1} = {red!20},
    row{2-Z} = {black!20},
    hlines = {solid}
  }
  HW & Chapter & Problems \\
  \expanded{\gethomework}
\end{tblr}

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_clear_new:N \g_donham_hw_tl

\cs_new:Nn \donham_add_hw:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \g_donham_hw_tl { #1 \\ }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \addhomework }{ m }
  {
    \donham_add_hw:n { #1 }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \gethomework { }
  {
    \tl_use:N \g_donham_hw_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\addhomework{1 & 1.6 & Do \# 1-10}

\addhomework{%
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2 & 2.1 & Do \# 1-10 \\
  & 2.2 & Do \# 1-10
}

\begin{tblr}[
    expand=\expanded,
    ]{
    width={\linewidth},
    colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1} = {red!20},
    row{2-Z} = {black!20},
    hlines = {solid}
  }
  HW & Chapter & Problems \\
  \expanded{\gethomework}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


LaTeX2e version [EDIT]
A LaTeX2e version, if needed:
\def\homework{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addhomework}{ m }{%
  \xdef\homework{\expandonce \homework #1 \\}%
}

using \expandonce from the etoolbox package.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \expandonce
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\homework{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addhomework}{ m }{%
  \xdef\homework{\expandonce \homework #1 \\}%
}

\begin{document}

\addhomework{1 & 1.6 & Do \# 1-10}

\addhomework{%
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2 & 2.1 & Do \# 1-10 \\
  & 2.2 & Do \# 1-10
}

\begin{tblr}[
    expand=\homework,
    ]{
    width={\linewidth},
    colspec={Q[c,0.25in]Q[c,0.5in]X},
    row{1} = {red!20},
    row{2-Z} = {black!20},
    hlines = {solid}
  }
  HW & Chapter & Problems \\
  \homework
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


Thank you for the suggestion.  If I understand correctly, your approach is to concatenate all of the assignments together first, and then insert that into the tblr.  I confess that the code between the ExplSyntax blocks is beyond my ability right now.  I will have to investigate this in the future.

@ChristopherDonham I think it's better to build dynamically the table content and use only one tabular. I added a LaTeX2e version if you prefer. But it worth looking at expl3 (or LaTeX3) interface: it's really powerful and very much clearer.
